# Building xfce4-dockbarx-plugin from source: glib-2.0 not found

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, xfce

Trying to follow these instructions: [github](https://github.com/M7S/xfce4-dockbarx-plugin), I get the following error in the log:

```
Checking for 'glib-2.0' >= 2.10
['/usr/bin/pkg-config', '--atleast-version=2.10', 'glib-2.0']
not found
from /home/zorath/xfce4-dockbarx-plugin-master: The configuration failed
```

The package appears to be present:

```
$ apt show libglib2.0-0
Package: libglib2.0-0
Version: 2.64.6-1~ubuntu20.04.3
Priority: important
Section: libs
Source: glib2.0
```

At first I thought the author could have written `glib-2.0` instead of `glib2.0`, but the string appears in the script several times and I'm pretty sure it will fail somewhere down the road if I just remove the hyphen.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When building from source you have to install the development package of the package you need. In your case you have to install the `libglib2.0-dev` package. You can do that by running:

```
sudo apt install libglib2.0-dev
```

Comment: Yay! Thanks for the quick answer. Now it fails on gtk+-2.0 but I think I get the idea.

Comment: Glad I could help! You know what to do now! :)